# EventLog Production

Tags: event-log

I have a console application that is responsible for saving a record in the Windows Event Viewer, but it does not work on a clean machine, despite having already installed the .Net Framework.

Create an installer which is responsible for creating the route `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\MyLogEvent`

When running the installed application, it does the whole process without throwing any errors, but it is not saving anything in the Event Viewer.

A strongname has already been added.

```
string origen = "ErrorGeneric";
EventLogEntryType severidad = EventLogEntryType.Error
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(origen))
{
     EventLog.CreateEventSource(origen, "MyLogEvent");
     while (!EventLog.SourceExists(origen))
     {
          Console.Write(".");
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
}
EventLog log = new EventLog() { Source = origen };
log.WriteEntry(logString.ToString(), severidad);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I needed to add the source to the installation, so that it was created in the windows registry